# why to use MappingJacksonValue on spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am seeing some of the rest services returning response as below

```
MappingJacksonValue result= new MappingJacksonValue(resultPojo);
return  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(result);
```

and for error

```
 return  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(new MappingJacksonValue("Error Message..."));
```

What is the use of wrapping object inside `MappingJacksonValue` if we can simply do something as below

```
return  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(resultPojo);

return  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Error Message...");
```

I see we can use filter options by using `MappingJacksonValue`, but if we are not using that, what is the benefit of using `MappingJacksonValue`.

**Note**

I am using `Spring boot`.

Comment: As noted unless you are using the extra features provided by the class there is no point in wrapping your pojo with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From documentation:

> A simple holder for the POJO to serialize via
>   [MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.html) along with further serialization
>   instructions to be passed in to the converter.

If you do not want to use [setFilters](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonValue.html#setFilters-com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.FilterProvider-) or [setSerializationView](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonValue.html#setSerializationView-java.lang.Class-) methods there is no point to use this class.